# REST API design and implementation for non CRUD operations in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rest, web-services, json-api

A user resource has properties `name`, `status` and so many other fields. A user can update his `name` but only an admin user can update the `status`.

In typical rest design, a `name` update could be

```
patch
/users/123
{
  name:"John"
}
```

Route will be

```
Route::apiResource('users',UserController::class);
```

Here the patch request will invoke the `update` method of the `UserController` class

Likewise, the `status` update is also a patch request which invokes the `update` method of the `UserController` class.

Now the situation is, both the updates are different actions from the perspective of business logic but from the REST design it is the same patch request that could be used for both operations.

So my questions are

1. As I said above, we have the same controller action `update` will get invoked for both operations. But in the case of the `status` update, we have to check if the logged-in user is admin.  How can I distinguish the operations and write the checking of the admin user
2. Are my understanding of REST correct?

Note: Please don't tell me `status` is a resource in that case imagine if every property of that user is having different business logic to be done before the update. Then, will every property be a resource?

Curiously waiting for the suggestions

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

2. 

Your understanding is correct though this can be still two endpoints from my perspective:

```
PATCH /current/user {"name": "John"}
PATCH /users/123 {"status": "deceised"}
```

1. 

You add access control to your code something like:

- if the user is an admin, then everything is fine
- else if the user is trying to edit their own profile and does not try to change the status property, then everything is fine
- otherwise 401

You should be able to do this based on the documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization I don't use Laravel, but after 1 min read, I think you need to add a Policy where you put the upper if-else statements and that's all.

Comment: Is the 1st route /current/user fit with REST standard? What exactly is `current` indicates; a resource? I was sticking with JSON API standards and I don't think this is recommended by https://jsonapi.org/format/

Comment: @KirenS It is always the current user you have in the JWT. Afaik. the representation of a resource can depend on the authorization data for example you can show or hide data or hyperlinks based on authorization, e.g. an admin can see certain links that a normal user cannot and use them for example in your case for changing the status. So in theory it is allowed to use such resources, which highly depend on the JWT. Though this is a very old debate, I am curious what other would say about this after 8+ years.

Comment: @KirenS Worst case you got a link for the current user for `GET /`, otherwise how would you display who is the current user in your responses? And if that logic can be applied, then we can have a separate resource for the same.